# How can I properly install bundler (gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

Having some serious bundler issues.

This series of events has been occurring after I installed a gem from the command line.

I'm using RVM (1.8.7) with a project-specific gemset. I also have a global gemset.

```
$ bundle install
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
$ bundle install
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
$
```

Any help would be much appreciated so I can get my dev environment back up and running!

Comment: what does 'rvm current' and 'gem list' return? Also, is there a .rvmc file associated with the project?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you did not used rvm installed ruby.

1. Start with updating RVM:

   ```
   rvm get stable
   ```
2. List which rubies are installed:

   ```
   rvm list
   ```
3. Use one of the listed rubies

   ```
   rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448
   ```
4. Make the ruby default so it is loaded with your shell

   ```
   rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448 --default
   ```

At any point make sure to carefully read the outputs, they will give you information about your system and if it is something is wrong how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo gem install bundler` for installing bundler in the root of you machine, no in the rvm